# Spring Shell: Is it possible to start spring shell at runtime on demand

Tags: spring-boot, spring-shell

I am runing a spring-boot app as a backend application within a docker container.
I want to be able to exec in a container and start a shellMethod to execute some admin stuff.
Is it possible start and stop a shell session within a container at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Shell provides the interactive shell, and the non-interactive mode.

Assuming Spring Boot 3.0.0 and Spring Shell 3.0.0-M3 or newer:

If you have a command like this:

```
@ShellComponent
public class Cli {

    @ShellMethod("Hello world")
    public String hello(@ShellOption(defaultValue = "world") String arg1){
        return "Hello " + arg1 + "!!";
    }
}
```

and you create `demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` using the spring boot maven plugin, for example:

```
./mvnw -Pnative clean spring-boot:build-image -DskipTests
```

You can execute commands directly against that docker image, like so:

```
$ docker run -it demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT hello FishingIsLife
```

To get:

```
Hello FishingIsLife
```

So you don't need to start/stop a shell session, just use the non-interactive mode of Spring Shell.

Comment: Cool, but is also possible form a running system? Like you connect to another host. docker ps shows you the running container. You exec in the container or execute a command directly to e.g. start a data export

Comment: "docker attach" allows you to connect to a running container, this is what I think you are trying to get to.  Additionally, I encourage you to take a look at Spring Cloud Task.  I'm happy to help further if you are interested in sharing more details.